# Divide u8 by usize

Tags: rust

I want to divide u8 and usize, like so:

```
let number: u8 = 100;
let mut listy = Vec::new();

for x in 0..10 {
   listy.push(x);
}

let divi = number / listy.len();
```

I get

```rust
error[E0277]: cannot divide `u8` by `usize`
 --> src/main.rs:9:23
  |
9 |     let divi = number / listy.len();
  |                       ^ no implementation for `u8 / usize`
  |
  = help: the trait `Div<usize>` is not implemented for `u8`
```

Is there no way to convert a usize to u8? Also, does the variable `divi` need to be a float?

Is there a precision float Rust?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your types match, both `u8`, `usize` or whatever you need (going to an upper type. Meaning that a `usize` can not be transformed to a `u8` normally, because it may not fit, but an `u8` to `usize` it could because it is guaranteed it will fit.).
As you ask float:

```rust
let div = number as f32 / listy.len() as f32;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41991ed9ebd7e36404f62aa899f265b0)

Comment: Isn't the max value of `usize` 2^64 - 1? Will that value being cast as f32 lose precision?

Comment: @JeffHolt Yea, an `f32` can store 24 bit integer exactly, and an `f64` can store 53 bit integers exactly. 2^24 is fairly achievable as an in-memory length, but 2^53 is not. Casting to `f64` here would be better.

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes. On 64-bits platforms even casting to `f64` will lose precision.

Comment: yes, you are both right. It was for the example, it is not a good usage. Usually would be better to use a fixed sized decimal crate as `fixed` or `rust_decimal`